# Not able to enable Panel which is outside the update panel from the update panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the scenario,

I have one update panel in which I have radio button.

On check of radio button I want to enable Panel which is outside the update panel.

I have tried following 2 things:

1. Placing the panel in another update panel didn't work.
2. Using JavaScript on click of radio button didn't work.

Comment: well formated question, but also put some code

Comment: put some code please. updatepanel might be rendered all over again lost its events. so you should use different way to bind the event. please put some code

Answer (score 0):

placing the panel in another updatepanel and set update mode as conditional.

You need to do one more thing

On check of radio button event you need to call update method of newly added update panel

```
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code sample helps you.

```
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udp1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Control_CheckedChanged"
                        Text="Text" GroupName="Group1" />
         <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Control_CheckedChanged"
                        Text="Text2" GroupName="Group1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udp2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text="Text"/>
         </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rb1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rb2" />
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

         protected void Control_CheckedChanged(object source, EventArgs e)
         {
            pnl1.Visible=rb1.Checked;
         }
```